# Visualization of an ensemble of sequences

Tags: time-series, data-visualization

What are the standard techniques of plotting a statistical ensemble of sequences?

I know the chaos game representation:

- H. Joel Jeffrey (1992), [Chaos game visualization of sequences](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0097-8493%2892%2990067-6). Computers & Graphics 16 (1): 25-33.

and two-dimensional plots:

- H.C. Lee Hao and Shu-yu Zhang (2000). [Fractals related to long dna sequences and complete genomes](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0960-0779%2898%2900182-9). Chaos, Solitons & Fractals, 11:825, [free pdf](http://nslij-genetics.org/dnacorr/haolee00.pdf).
- J. Rodriguez-Laguna, PM, M. Ibáñez Berganza, M. Lewenstein, G. Sierra (2011). [Qubism: self-similar visualization of many-body wavefunctions](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.3560), arXiv:1112.3560 [quant-ph].

Are there any others?

Edit:

I am the most interested in finite alphabets (say, of the order of 2 to 9), with no internal structure and with sequences of any length (also infinite; but in practice 8-18 letters are fine for me). However, other approaches are welcome as well.

Comment: More information would be helpful. Is it a sequence of finite alphabets? Does the alphabet have any structure? How long is your sequence? How many do you have?

Comment: @Memming Edited my post. What do you mean by "How many do you have?"?

Comment: Since you said "ensemble", I'm assuming you have multiple sequences, right?

Comment: @Memming Yes. The point is I don't want to visualize a single sequence but the probabilities of the occurrence of any sequence (or their count if it is from empirical data).